# ODE with discontinuous function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This exercise was given to me: to solve the following ODE over $[0,+\infty)$ $$y'+y=H(t),$$ where $$H(t) = \begin{cases} 
          1 & 0\leq t\leq 1 \\
          -1 & t\gt 1 
       \end{cases}
      $$

So i've multiplied both sides by $e^t$ to get that the ODE is equivalent to $$(e^ty)' = e^tH(t).$$

However RHS of this clearly doesn't satisfy IVT, so it is not the derivative of a function, therefore the ODE has no solutions. Is this correct or am i missing something?

Comment: You are correct, there won't be a smooth solution to this problem. On the other hand it is possible to formulate a weak version of this differential equation, which will have a solution. This solution won't be differentiable everywhere. Have you learned about Sobolev-Spaces, weak derivatives or Rademachers theorem for Lipschitz functions yet? These things usually do not come up in an ODE course, they are usually done in a partial differential equations course.

Comment: @humanStampedist i haven't, this weirdly came up in a introductory differential equations course. I'd like to learn about these topics tho, if you would be so kind to elaborate on what a weak version of this DE means in that context.

Comment: @ Galinha Galinha : It is a good example for nonexistence of a smooth solution, hence it came up. Here you can actually calculate a solution which is smooth outside of $t=1$. Try integrating $(e^ty)' = e^t H(t)$. You will have to make a distinction of cases, i.e. $t<1$, $t>1$. This will lead to a function, which is a solution outside of $t=1$ and is continuous and even Lipschitz. And this is essentially what a weak solution is, you satisfy the ODE outside of a set of 'length' zero (i.e. Lebesgue measure equals zero) while it still being continuous....

Comment: ...The whole story is quite more involved though . Try reading the book by Evans: Partial differential equations. It is good start in this direction. In there look up Sobolev Spaces and weak derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be solved individually for $0\leq t\leq 1$ and $t>1$ and then use the free constants to make the solution continuous.

For $0\leq t\leq 1$, the equation reads
$$
y'+y=1.
$$
The general solution to the equation above is
$$
y=1+c_1 e^{-t},
$$
where $c_1$ is a free constant.
In the formula above,  $y_p=1$ is a particular solution and $y_h=c_1 e^{-t}$ is the general solution of the homogenous problem.

For $t> 1$, the equation reads
$$
y'+y=-1.
$$
The general solution to the equation above is
$$
y=-1+c_2 e^{-t},
$$
where $c_2$ is another free constant.

So we have
$$
y=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1+c_1 e^{-t},&0\leq t\leq 1\\
-1+c_2 e^{-t},& t>1.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
The continuity condition reads $c_2=2+c_1$.

Thus
$$
y=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1+c_1 e^{-t},&0\leq t\leq 1\\
-1+(2+c_1) e^{-t},& t>1
\end{array}
\right.
$$
is the general solution with free constant $c_1$.

@humanStampedist is right in that this type of problem, in principle should be done in the context of distributions. However, in a case like that where only one allows the derivative to be discontinuous, the techniques covered in a first ODE course can be used as above. Alternatively, it can be solved using the Laplace Transform method. Laplace transforms are often covered in an ODE course and that would be a typical problem for the application of that method.

Comment: a differentiable condition is needed: $y'(1^+)=y'(1^-)$, that is, the left-side derivative is equal to the right-side derivative at $x=1$. So $c_1=-1$.

Comment: @Black Mild There is a discontinuity in the first derivative due to $H$ on the RHS of the ODE. This is why ′ is discontinuous. If you implement the condition you suggest for $y'$ at $t=1$, one gets the equation $1-c_1e^{-1}=−1−(2+c_1)e^{−1}$. The constant $c_1$ gets cancelled and we end up with $1+e^{-1}=0$, which cannot be satisfied. This problem is such that $y'$ has to be discontinuous for it to be a solution. More formally, all this can be framed in the context of distributions, but, in this particular case, it seems to me it can be handled with ''normal'' ODE theory.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Laplace transform over

$$
y'(t)+y(t) = \theta (t)-2 \theta (t-1)
$$

where $\theta(t)$ is the Heaviside $\theta$ function, we have

$$
\mathcal{L}[y] = \frac{e^{-s} \left(e^s s y_0+e^s-2\right)}{s (s+1)}
$$

with inverse (solution)

$$
y(t) = 1 + e^{-t} (2 e \theta (t-1)+y_0-1)-2 \theta (t-1)
$$

Comment: I don't know a lot about Laplace transforms. Why does the Laplace transform give a "solution" (that isn't really a solution because the ODE as stated has no solution). Is it because integrals don't care about null measure sets?

Comment: This is a perfect solution in the sense of distributions/generalized functions.

Comment: I concur with @Cesareo. The solution given in Cesareo's answer and in the answer above that are perfectly good solutions. In fact, they are two representations of the same solution: they are written differently and obtained with different methods.

Comment: In the discussion with @ humanStampedist , the conclusion was about the nonexistence of a ``smooth solution''. The solution given in Cesareo's answer and, alternatively, given in my answer above, the derivative is discontinuous at $t=1$, thus not smooth there. Still good solutions to the problem.